# What is the probability that the triangle inequality will hold on exponential random numbers?

Tags: probability

I have three i.i.d exponential random numbers $X,Y$ and $Z$ that have the same parameter $\lambda$.

I am interested in calculating the probability that the triangle inequality holds for $X,Y,Z$. That is,

$$\Pr\left[X+Y\ge Z\right].$$

Comment: Why does it matter that this is a matrix? Why not just consider $\mathbb{P}[a+b\geq c]$ where $a,b,c$ are i.i.d. exponential random variables? In this case, this is equivalent to asking a question about the cumulative density of a linear combination of exponential random variables.

Comment: You are right, it does not matter. I missed that. So, I have to calculate $\Pr[a+b\ge c]$ for $a,b,c$ i.i.d exponential random variables.

Comment: If you edit the question it might get more attention. Having said that, this might just be a simple computation now.

Comment: I see a paper online, "On linear combinations of independent exponential variables." This might have the expression you are looking for (since you really only care about the random variable $x=a+b-c$).

Comment: Thank you. I will look at that paper.